# jquery plugin for report

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Is there any jquery plugin which expands on click ,basically iwant to show a report on click and then minimise back on click again.

Thanks..

Comment: what kind of report you want to show , is it a pdf or html or doc?

Comment: you can do multple things with various kind of animations...jquery has animate functoin too

Comment: @gov:it is a html report,and may be lengthy scroll bar preferred..

Comment: Please give appropriate heading to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show and hide an existing element then can do something like

```
<a href-"#" id="expcoll">Click me to toggle</a>
<div id="report">
     your report content goes here
</div>

$(function(){
    $("#expcoll").click(function(){
         // show or hide the report
         $("#report").toggle();
         // if you want a slide effect 
         //$("#report").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

If you want to load the HTML report data dynamically then you can use AJAX calls in jQuery and load the result into the report div.

Comment: we don't know what he wants , he wants to show some report it seems. normally most of reports will be in a pdf format , he maywant to show that in a new window and all

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want something like [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Comment: No this would be a lengthy report

Comment: @rajeev , please mention the format of the report...is it HTML format you are preparing at runtime or some pdf ,doc reading from some remote location.

Comment: if it is html , show nicely on a popup close it as mentioned by rahul

Comment: @gov:it is a html report.basically a table

Answer (score 0):

Rajeev ,

do the following ,

1) Store all the report html in hidden div

```
  <div id ="reportID" style="display:none">drop all your html here </div>
```

when you click your report div ,

2) show the div with jquery

```
$('#reportID').show();
```

when you click your report div again

do

```
$('#repordID').hide();
```

you can bind the events as mentioned by rahul

let me know if you need any more info

Comment: If you are attaching the event to the report div itself and if you are hiding the report then how will the click event occur?

Comment: When u attach the click event it would rather call a function rit..that can be done

Comment: for clicking....we can maintain a separate text which says show report and hide report

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle using a basic jquery-ui dialog to do 200 line dummy logs

http://jsfiddle.net/generalhenry/T36e8/

I included css to force the content to scroll if needed.